# Keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu 10.04: guide for Mac users

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-10.04, macbook, compiz

I'm looking for a good ***mac specific*** guide to all the keyboard shortcuts available in Ubuntu 10.04 (with Compiz). I say 'mac specific' as I'm on this type of machinery, and the keyboard over here is different.

Any good guide will be appreciated, but I'm looking for the Spaces / Exposé-like features. Specifically, I want to know how to:

1. switch desktops,
2. show all applications on the current / all desktop(s), and
3. show the desktop.

I have grown severely accustomed to these features in OS X, so I want them also in Ubuntu!

FYI, I'm running a MacBook 4,1, Intel Core 2 Duo, 4GB RAM and a pretty crappy graphics card - please comment if any further info is needed.

Cheers!

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm not looking for an 'OS X feel' on Ubuntu, I just want to know how to use Ubuntu with a Mac keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your three questions:

1. Control + Option + Left/Right
2. Super + W to show all windows in current workspace; Super + A to show all windows across workspaces (you may need to set your Super key; this is like the Windows key)
3. Control + Option + D

Here's a good guide for you: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts.  It isn't Mac specific, but the only real differences are that the documentation says Alt, but we use the Option key (which also has Alt written on it), and that you may need to set your Super key to Command or another key of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a mac specific guide, but there is a wonderful theme called [Mac4Lin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mac4lin/) that you may like or already use.

As for Spaces/Exposé, just install [CompizConfig Simple](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/simple-ccsm) (`sudo apt-get install simple-ccsm`) and open that up (Simple CompizConfig Settings Manager in the menu) and start tweaking away. There's far more good stuff in the CompizConfig Manager (not simple) but any Mac pundit would call it a "UX Nightmare".

**Update**: You may actually need to get CompizConfig not simple (`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`). Make sure you set aside 25 minutes at the least to set that thing up and to look up documentation xD.

Comment: To clarify I'm not looking for an 'OS X feel' on Ubuntu, I just wanna know how to use Ubuntu with a Mac keyboard.